# Excel VBA - Accessing transit_details array from Google directions API using XML

Tags: vba, excel

I am accessing the Google Directions API from Excel using VBA. I would like to be able to access the transit_details array in the Google directions API when retrieving transit directions using XML from VBA so I can get number of stops etc. At the moment I have code that gives me basic directions but I don't get stop numbers etc for transit directions:
The following is the Google Directions API webpage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

```
'Get Directions
        For Each nodeRoute In .SelectSingleNode("//route/leg").ChildNodes
        If nodeRoute.BaseName = "step" Then
            strInstructions = strInstructions & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("html_instructions").text & " - " & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("distance/text").text & vbCrLf
                   End If
    Next

    strInstructions = CleanHTML(strInstructions) 'Removes MetaTag information from HTML result to convert to plain text.

Else
    strError = .SelectSingleNode("//status").text
    GoTo errorHandler
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an XML Parser for VBA so that you can reference the XML with it's native structure.  I'm not sure if there's XML parsers for VBA, I'll look when I get home from work (no time now)

Comment: I can get the departure and arrival times but I don't know how to work out whether the current step is a walking, driving or transit step for example, a route may start off by walking to a bus stop, Catch bus 55 etc.